# Count number of events that happened in wrong order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I search within a chronologically ordered group, and count if there was a certain event that happened prior to another?

My data appears as:

```
id   | flow_nme | prod | RowFilter |
'20' | A2       | 1    | 1         |
'20' | A3       | 1    | 2         |
'30' | A3       | 1    | 1         |
'30  | A2       | 1    | 2         |
'40' | C1       | 1    | 1         |
'40' | C2       | 1    | 2         |
'40' | A3       | 1    | 3         |
'40' | A2       | 1    | 4         |
```

RowFilter contains the chronological sorting for each id group.  The names A2, A3, C1, and C2 have no true meaning and are dummy names.  The RowFilter has been created from a time stamp indicating which order the events occurred in.  The only thing determining which order the events "should" have occurred in is the normal process flow.  In essence, I want to count the times when the normal process flow did not occur.

So I would like to count the instances for each id that A3 occured before A2 and C2 before A3.

My expected output should be something like:

```
type  | count |
A3-A2 | 2     |
C2-A3 | 1     |
```

I've tried using OVER and PARTITION BY, but must be doing something very wrong.

I will work on coming up with code to mock up the data as soon as I have time to make this question easily reproducible.  I am more familiar with R than with SQL, so it isn't immediately apparent to me what that code will look like.

Comment: What do you mean by chronological sorting? And how do you know what the right order should be?

Comment: Presumably correct order is lexicographical (ie natural) order

Comment: What if the `flow_nme`s occur more than once for a given `id`?

Comment: By chronological sorting I am referring to the fact that RowFilter is actually representative of time.  The right order is determined by a specific process.  So, in my made up example A2 should happen before A3 and C2 should happen before A3.

Comment: You don't have anything in your data here to indicate that A3 comes before or after A2 unless you can use flow_nme as the ordering column. And how do you know it didn't skip a step since you have no master list? And why is the "first" set of steps the accurate one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+ (for [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [**`concat()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)).

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (derived table would work too) with `lead()` to find the `next_flow_nme` and `concat()` to concatenate the two `flow_nme`s for `type`, filtered to `where flow_nme > next_flow_nme`. Then `group by` and `count(*)`.

```
;with cte as (
select id, flow_nme, prod, rowfilter
  , next_flow_nme = lead(flow_nme) over (order by id, rowfilter)
from t
)
select 
    type = concat(flow_nme,'-',next_flow_nme)
  , [count]=count(*)
from cte
where flow_nme > next_flow_nme
group by concat(flow_nme,'-',next_flow_nme)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NHW71132

returns:

```
+-------+-------+
| type  | count |
+-------+-------+
| A3-A2 |     2 |
| C2-A3 |     1 |
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that assumes that you have unique `flow_nme`s for each `id.`  This puts puts the values in separate columns:

```
select sum(case when rf_a3 < rf_a2 then 1 else 0 end) as a3_a2,
       sum(case when rf_c2 < rf_a3 then 1 else 0 end) as c2_a3
from (select id,
             min(case when flow_nme = 'A3' then row_filter end) as rf_a3,
             min(case when flow_nme = 'A2' then row_filter end) as rf_a2,
             min(case when flow_nme = 'C2' then row_filter end) as rf_c2
      from t
      group by id
     ) t;
```

You can unpivot this if you like.  I like using `apply` for this purpose:

```
select v.*
from (select sum(case when rf_a3 < rf_a2 then 1 else 0 end) as a3_a2,
             sum(case when rf_c2 < rf_a3 then 1 else 0 end) as c2_a3
      from (select id,
                   min(case when flow_nme = 'A3' then row_filter end) as rf_a3,
                   min(case when flow_nme = 'A2' then row_filter end) as rf_a2,
                   min(case when flow_nme = 'C2' then row_filter end) as rf_c2
            from t
            group by id
           ) t
     ) t cross apply
     (values ('a3_a2', a3_a2), ('c2_a3', c2_a3)) v(type, count);
```